# Android java VpnService

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь написать клиент для VPN сервера. Нашел документацию https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html но не могу найти в интернете рабочих примеров. Подскажите пожалуйста, может кто то сталкивался с это темой..

Comment: я бы взял с плеймаркета и декомпилировал

Comment: Ну должны же в интернете быть рабочие примеры

Comment: А что конкретно в документации не понятно?

Comment: вот примеры: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android+vpn&type=Repositories

Comment: @ajvs На английском и китайском есть, а на пигмейском может и не быть запросто

Comment: Все что я нашел на англ это урывок кода который у меня не работает. Мне бы такой минимальный пример кода